# Delete row with empty line csv

Tags: bash, unix, csv, awk

```
1 1479870 5022248660 

1 1911574 3015889020 8

1 1569783 5029193930
```

Output should be

```
1 1911574 3015889020 8
```

I used

```
awk '$4!=""' number.csv
```

but it didn't work. Can anyone give me a clue?

Comment: Why don't you keep the first and last lines? They aren't empty.

Comment: It should work. Maybe the input file has a non default awk field separator.

Answer (score 2):

Keep only lines with more than three columns:

```
awk 'NF>3' file
```

Output:

```
1 1911574 3015889020 8
```

---

[8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)